# Unable to run test with Fonemonkey

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, automation, fonemonkey

I have downloaded Fonemokey from Gorillalogic.com and followed the Documentation provided with it to set up the fonemonkey with my project. However when I am running the project i have got following errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestSuite", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFoneMonkeyOCUnit.5.5b.a(FoneMonkey+OCUnit.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestObserver", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFoneMonkeyOCUnit.5.5b.a(FoneMonkey+OCUnit.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestLog", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFoneMonkeyOCUnit.5.5b.a(FoneMonkey+OCUnit.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

I am using xCode 4.2 and iOS5. I have already included senTestingFramework and set the Other Linker Flages to **-all_load**. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got stuck with the same problem - and first I thought about blaming FoneMonkey :-)

But then I tried to just add a simple TestClass that extends SenTestCase, and that turned up with the same problem (I removed the FoneMonkeyOCUnit lib prior to that test).
So I figured the problem must be within my project setup and not FoneMonkey.

It turned out my Framework searchpath was wrong - I added this to my Framework searchpath "$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks"

And now it is working in xCode - next up is to make FoneMonkey work from Jenkins.

Comment: u save my ass.. u r my hero :)